# On hamming hypercubes

Tags: computer-science, coding-theory

Regularly in a Hamming hypercube, the vertices are labelled so that edge difference (minimum number of edges traversed between two vertices) equals Hamming distance (path difference). That is lower the edge difference, lower the hamming distance(path difference) of the labelled vertices. Can we label the cube so that lower the edge difference, higher will the Hamming distance be? Not all pairs of words will satisfy this property (for instance try labeling the 2-cube). However, is there a lower bound on how many close vertices any vertex can have and still have the property? Any references for this would help. This does sound like anticodes. However I am unsure.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Again updated the question.

Comment: Hmm. If the dimension of the cube is even, then by taking the bitwise complements of the odd weight labels we get a labelling such that the labels of the immediate neighbors are at Hamming distance $n-1$. Can't do better than that since there always is only a single label at the maximum Hamming distance from a given label, and you cannot cover all the $n$ immediate neighbors (=vertices with edge difference $1$) with that same label. I don't see a way of improving the situation with vertices at edge distance two (I mean globally - in a way that works with all vertices).